# Is there a less manual way of changing database properties for all databases in an instance?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I've recently audited a SharePoint server and found configurations that are against best practice.

I'm hoping there is better and quicker way than right-clicking and changing these settings manually on over 100 database.

For instance, all the databases are set to autogrow by 10MB and the log files are set to autogrow by 1%.  I'd like for these to be a set number and not a percentage.

Any resources or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I often generate T-SQL like this:

```
select 'ALTER DATABASE ' + quotename(name) + ' MODIFY FILE (...)'
from sys.databases
where databaseIsMisconfigured = 1
```

Select the entire column, past it into a new window and F5.

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for, thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

you could script out all settings. make the changes you want in the the GUI but instead of click OK to apply the change, click script at the top of the window and the SQL for your changes will be scripted out. You will now just have to change database name/file names/ sizes/ etc for each database.

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'test', FILEGROWTH = 102400KB )
GO
```

if you wanted to do all databases, you could do something like this although it might not be appropriate to set what ever setting you are changing to the same value for each database.

```
select d.name,f.name,'ALTER DATABASE ['+d.name+'] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'''+f.name+''', FILEGROWTH = 102400KB );' from sys.databases d
inner join sys.master_files f 
on d.database_id = f.database_id
```

Just had another thought, you could use [Policy based management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510667.aspx).  this will allow you to set one policy and apply it to numerous databases.

Comment: I thought of that, but that seems just as manual as right-clicking and making the changes.  I was hoping for some sort of TSQL code that could parse the databases dynamically without having to specifically delineate the database names.

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147659/get-list-of-databases-from-sql-server) could help?